# IPSEC Phase 1 error

Tags: vpn, ipsec, ike

Was does the MM_NO_STATE usually mean when having errors bringing phase 1 up?

```
IPv4 Crypto ISAKMP SA
dst             src             state          conn-id status
X.X.X.122  X.X.X.107    MM_NO_STATE          0 ACTIVE
```

Debug log:

```
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: IPSEC(sa_request): ,
  (key eng. msg.) OUTBOUND local= X.X.X.107:500, remote= X.X.X.122:500,
    local_proxy= LOCAL.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.255.0/256/0,
    remote_proxy= REMOTE.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.240.0/256/0,
    protocol= ESP, transform= esp-aes 256 esp-sha256-hmac  (Tunnel), 
    lifedur= 3600s and 4608000kb, 
    spi= 0x0(0), conn_id= 0, keysize= 256, flags= 0x0
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): SA request profile is (NULL)
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP: Created a peer struct for X.X.X.122, peer port 500
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP: New peer created peer = 0x21027558 peer_handle = 0x80000022
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP: Locking peer struct 0x21027558, refcount 1 for isakmp_initiator
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP: local port 500, remote port 500
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP: set new node 0 to QM_IDLE      
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP: Find a dup sa in the avl tree during calling isadb_insert sa = 3D3B8698
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):Can not start Aggressive mode, trying Main mode.
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):found peer pre-shared key matching X.X.X.122
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-rfc3947 ID
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-07 ID
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-03 ID
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-02 ID
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_IPSEC, IKE_SA_REQ_MM
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_READY  New State = IKE_I_MM1 

Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): beginning Main Mode exchange
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to X.X.X.122 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:25:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet
Feb 18 09:25:46.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
Feb 18 09:25:46.732: ISAKMP (0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 1 of 5: retransmit phase 1
Feb 18 09:25:46.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:25:46.732: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to X.X.X.122 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:25:46.732: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
Feb 18 09:25:51.340: ISAKMP:(0):purging node -1205386052
Feb 18 09:25:51.340: ISAKMP:(0):purging node 359996904
Feb 18 09:25:56.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
Feb 18 09:25:56.732: ISAKMP (0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 2 of 5: retransmit phase 1
Feb 18 09:25:56.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:25:56.732: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to X.X.X.122 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:25:56.732: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
Feb 18 09:26:01.340: ISAKMP:(0):purging SA., sa=3D3A9E34, delme=3D3A9E34
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: IPSEC(key_engine): request timer fired: count = 1,
  (identity) local= X.X.X.107:0, remote= X.X.X.122:0,
    local_proxy= LOCAL.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.255.0/256/0,
    remote_proxy= REMOTE.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.240.0/256/0
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: IPSEC(sa_request): ,
  (key eng. msg.) OUTBOUND local= X.X.X.107:500, remote= X.X.X.122:500,
    local_proxy= LOCAL.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.255.0/256/0,
    remote_proxy= REMOTE.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.240.0/256/0,
    protocol= ESP, transform= esp-aes 256 esp-sha256-hmac  (Tunnel), 
    lifedur= 3600s and 4608000kb, 
    spi= 0x0(0), conn_id= 0, keysize= 256, flags= 0x0
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP: set new node 0 to QM_IDLE      
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP:(0):SA is still budding. Attached new ipsec request to it. (local X.X.X.107, remote X.X.X.122)
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP: Error while processing SA request: Failed to initialize SA
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP: Error while processing KMI message 0, error 2.
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP (0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 3 of 5: retransmit phase 1
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to X.X.X.122 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
Feb 18 09:26:16.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
Feb 18 09:26:16.732: ISAKMP (0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 4 of 5: retransmit phase 1
Feb 18 09:26:16.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:26:16.732: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to X.X.X.122 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:26:16.732: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
Feb 18 09:26:26.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
Feb 18 09:26:26.732: ISAKMP (0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 5 of 5: retransmit phase 1
Feb 18 09:26:26.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:26:26.732: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to X.X.X.122 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:26:26.732: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):peer does not do paranoid keepalives.

Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):deleting SA reason "Death by retransmission P1" state (I) MM_NO_STATE (peer X.X.X.122)
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: IPSEC(key_engine): request timer fired: count = 2,
  (identity) local= X.X.X.107:0, remote= X.X.X.122:0,
    local_proxy= LOCAL.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.255.0/256/0,
    remote_proxy= REMOTE.LAN.SUBNET/255.255.240.0/256/0
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):deleting SA reason "Death by retransmission P1" state (I) MM_NO_STATE (peer X.X.X.122) 
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP: Unlocking peer struct 0x21027558 for isadb_mark_sa_deleted(), count 0
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP: Deleting peer node by peer_reap for X.X.X.122: 21027558
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):deleting node 1892890669 error FALSE reason "IKE deleted"
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):deleting node -2013997155 error FALSE reason "IKE deleted"
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PHASE1_DEL
Feb 18 09:26:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_I_MM1  New State = IKE_DEST_SA 

Feb 18 09:26:36.732: IPSEC(key_engine): got a queue event with 1 KMI message(s)
Feb 18 09:27:26.732: ISAKMP:(0):purging node 1892890669
Feb 18 09:27:26.732: ISAKMP:(0):purging node -2013997155
Feb 18 09:27:36.732: ISAKMP:(0):purging SA., sa=3D3B8698, delme=3D3B869
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MM_NO_STATE means Main Mode No State.  That is, the state machine is still in the initial state because it hasn't received any response from the peer.

```
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
Feb 18 09:26:06.732: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to X.X.X.122 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
```

This seems to indicate that this router is sending IKE data to the peer, but the peer is not responding.  You should verify that the peer is configured correctly.